# Using commas with "In 1900," after conjunction (and) / Comma, mid-sentence, conjunction, date, year

Tags: commas

Example sentence :

> In 1900, the first World Cup game was hosted.

This is easy. You put a comma because you're introducing a new timeline.

BUT my question is how do I put in commas when the above sentence is used in mid-sentence, like after conjunction "and"? (don't mind the content/context of all example sentences)

> In 1900, the first male World Cup game was hosted 'and in 1910 the' first female World Cup was hosted.

Please fix the grammar / writing devices in ' '.

Comment: This is a matter of style. Consult your style guide. *The Chicago Manual of Style* would accept these: *In 1900 the first male World Cup game was hosted, and in 1910 the first female World Cup was hosted. In 1900, the first male World Cup game was hosted, and in 1910, the first female World Cup was hosted.*

Comment: This is not text chat, please spell out words like "you" and "because"

Comment: I've never come across "a new timeline" as a grammatical category. "In 1910" would normally be called a prepositional phrase functioning as an adverbial phrase.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to EL&U. In fact the first comma is not necessary but after the **and** you need a comma both before and after the phrase **in 1910** because that is parenthetical (you could put it in brackets). This gives you the sentence

> In 1900 the first male World Cup was hosted and, in 1910, the first female World Cup was hosted.

The alternative is to put the dates *after* the details of the events giving

> The first male World Cup was hosted in 1900 and the first female World Cup was hosted in 1910.

Using this form it is also possible to omit repetition by writing

> The first male World Cup was hosted in 1900 and the first female one in 1910.

**Amendment**
As I am quite old and British I did a little online searching to see if I could find a rule about commas before new timelines that I has never heard of but I failed to find one. The only consistent rule I could find was the insertion of commas around the expanded date when the format **day name, date** is used. For instance

> On Sunday, December 11th, we will have our Christingle Service

Or, in American style dating,

> On Sunday, 11th Decenmber, we will have our Christingle Service.

This is presented as a rule for writing dates but is, in fact, a further example of surrounding parenthetical information with commas since the expanded date is a repetition and clarification of the day of the week.

If you can give some documentation of the "comma before a new timeline" rule I would be interested to see it.